# Hapi v17 - Joi schema for file responses

Tags: javascript, hapi.js, content-disposition, joi

How do I write the Joi schema for a file that I am sending as a response?

My route returns this   `return h.file(filename, { mode: 'attachment'}).code(201);` and well, the `content-dispostion` response header is `attachment; filename=entries.csv`.

I can maybe check the object structure of the response that's going out but is there a way Joi provides a property to check for files in the response?

[Here's the Github issue you might wanna track](https://github.com/glennjones/hapi-swagger/issues/130)

Answer (score 1):

I misunderstood the question - it was about validating response headers, not request ones.
Short answer: **it cannot be done.**

Long answer:

Based on **hapijs 17.5.3** https://hapijs.com/api#-routeoptionsresponseoptions it seemed doable with a function:

```
server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/file',
    options: {
        handler: (request, h) => {

            return h.file('foobar.csv', { mode: 'attachment'}).code(201);
        },
        response: {
            schema: async (value, options) => {

                console.log('validating response:', value);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

But this approach **doesn't work**.
It's not supported by hapijs, you'll get an exception from line 151: https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/blob/76fcd7fa97747c92501b912d64db459d7172cb26/lib/validation.js
which is:

```
if (!response.isBoom &&
    request.response.variety !== 'plain') {

    throw Boom.badImplementation('Cannot validate non-object response');
}
```

---

here's how you can validate headers on **requests**:

```
'use strict';
const Joi = require('joi');
const ErrorHandler = require('../handlers/errorHandler');

const fileUploadValidator = {
    config: {
        validate: {
            params: {
                env: Joi.string().min(2).max(10).required()
            },
            query: {
                id: Joi.number().integer().min(0).required()
            },
            headers: Joi.object({
                'x-request-id': Joi.string().guid().required(),
                'content-disposition': Joi.string().regex(/attachment;\s*filename=.+\.csv/gi).insensitive().required()
            }).options({ allowUnknown: true }),
            failAction: ErrorHandler.apply_genericHandler
        }
    }
};

module.exports = fileUploadValidator;
```

Route definition:

```
server.route({
    method: 'POST',
    path: '/{env}/v1/fileUpload',
    handler: FileUploadHandler.apply,
    options: FileUploadValidator.config
});
```

you may need to tweak it a bit. I've built it based on your question.

Comment: Thanks, I thought there'd be something like Joi.file() to check the response body. Can you please put the headers code inside response headers? Because this will check the headers of request and I am sending the file not receiving it,

Comment: Based on Hapi documentation, I thought it can be done, but it cannot. I'll update my response

Comment: Gosh! Thanks for the effort. It's lovely! But the new code that you added above tries to validate response body whereas it will also work if we are able to check the response headers, for example, here the `Content-disposition` type. Can that be done?

Comment: in theory, this method: ```schema: async (value, options) => {``` has access to the header and could validate it, but because hapi doesn't allow it validation for body-less responses, it's impossible ;(